# javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ not available

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm dealing with **Java** and **BlueCove** in order to find the bluetooth devices.

I've created a **Maven** Project and I've added the BlueCove dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.bluecove</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluecove</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm working on **Ubuntu**, I've installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez libbluetooth-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep bluez-tools
```

I've copied and pasted an example [from here](https://www.javaquery.com/2014/07/bluecove-bluetooth-remote-device.html), basically the following:

```
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;

public class RemoteDeviceDiscovery {

    public Vector getDevices() {
    /* Create Vector variable */
    final Vector devicesDiscovered = new Vector();
    try {
        final Object inquiryCompletedEvent = new Object();
        /* Clear Vector variable */
        devicesDiscovered.clear();

        /* Create an object of DiscoveryListener */
        DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() {

            public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
                /* Get devices paired with system or in range(Without Pair) */
                devicesDiscovered.addElement(btDevice);
            }

            public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
                /* Notify thread when inquiry completed */
                synchronized (inquiryCompletedEvent) {
                    inquiryCompletedEvent.notifyAll();
                }
            }

            /* To find service on bluetooth */
            public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
            }

            /* To find service on bluetooth */
            public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
            }
        };

        synchronized (inquiryCompletedEvent) {
            /* Start device discovery */
            boolean started = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);
            if (started) {
                System.out.println("wait for device inquiry to complete...");
                inquiryCompletedEvent.wait();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* Return list of devices */
    return devicesDiscovered;
    }
}
```

But when I run my program I get the error:

```
javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ not available
```

at this line:

```
boolean started = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent().startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, listener);
```

I've already seen other answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047048/java-bluetooth-api-bluecove-issue) with no success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I know I'm super late, but I was googling the same problem.
This worked for me on ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt install blueman libbluetooth* bluez*
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

After you can check the bluetooth status:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

Hope you see this, and if you do, that this helped :)