# BlueCove com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ not available

Tags: java, bluez, bluecove, jsr82

I am trying to connect Bluetooth in Java using Bluecove, below is the code I am trying to run. It keeps giving me the error
`Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ not available`

```
package blue.first;

import javax.bluetooth.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Pair_Device {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("bluecove.stack", "bluez");

        LocalDevice device = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();

        RemoteDevice[] remoteDevice = device.getDiscoveryAgent().retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.PREKNOWN);
        for(RemoteDevice d: remoteDevice) {
            System.out.println("Device Name : "+d.getFriendlyName(false));
            System.out.println("Bluetooth Address : "+d.getBluetoothAddress() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I have installed BlueZ version 5.64-0ubuntu1, I also installed the bluecove-2.1.0.jar file and added it to the build path. I Checked the requirements of bluecove to function in it's documentation and also made changes accordingly, which included making a symbolic link of libbluetooth.so and installing libbluetooth-dev. I also tried reading a [similar article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704036/javax-bluetooth-bluetoothstateexception-bluecove-com-intel-bluetooth-bluetooths) on this and had no success.

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong here? I use Ubuntu 22.04 and Java version '18.0.2-ea' and Idea IntelliJ. Java version is SE.

Comment: You may try downgrading your BlueZ version to a version that BlueCove can work with, BlueCove is kinda ancient, so compatibility issues are expected